# custom library: how to handle dependencies?

Tags: android, dependencies, shared-libraries, android-appcompat, okhttp

I don't know how to best deal with including dependencies in an Android library and cannot find any clear explanation elsewhere.

I have created an Android library that includes these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Is it "good practice" to include the dependencies like this? what happens when my library is included in an app, and the app itself includes the same dependencies? how are these "duplicate" dependencies handled?

What is the best way to include dependencies in an Android library if the possibility exists that an app using the library may also include the same dependencies?

Answer (score 4):

**The best practice** is to avoid duplicates (because it can make problem with your build), you can add exclude clauses in each project `build.gradle` file.

**For example:**

```
compile('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

**The default behaviour is to settle on the newest version of the requested dependency** - the newest means the highest version number.

If you want to check if there are duplicates you can visualize library dependencies in tree with the command:

```
gradlew -q dependencies yourProject:dependencies --configuration compile
```

You can find [more information here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec:listing_dependencies)

Comment: Thanks. As I would not know if an app using my library will have the same dependency as the one I have included in my library, does this mean that using "exclude" for my dependency will cause the app to use my dependency if non-existent in the app and use the latest version of the two if it is included in the app?